# Windows 7 and Group Policy Results Wizard

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

I have a Windows Server 2008 domain controller with a bunch of Windows XP and 7 hosts. When I attempt to use Group Policy Results Wizard on some of the Windows 7 boxes I receive the error "Access Denied." Windows Firewall is not enabled on these machines. What gives?

It operates at Windows 2000 functional level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this before and after some lost hair as well as rounds on support calls I found this link.

check it out

http://www.minasi.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=20825

According to a post on there, running the following commands in Command Prompt solves the issue:

```
cd /d %windir%\system32 
regsvr32 /n /I userenv.dll 
cd wbem 
mofcomp scersop.mof 
gpupdate /force
gpresult
```